# ¿Cómo modificar las claves de un diccionario?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un diccionario donde las claves son los dias de la semana, y los valores el numero de orden de estas.

```
dias = {
   "lunes": 1,
   "martes": 2,
   "miercoles": 3,
   "jueves": 4,
   "viernes": 5,
   "sabado": 6,
   "domingo": 7
   }
```

Lo que prentendo hacer es simplemente transformar en mayusculas las 7 claves, por lo que hice lo siguiente:

```
keys = list(dias)
x = 0
for k in keys:
    keys[x] = k.upper()
    x += 1
y = 0
for i in dias:
    dias[keys[y]] = dias.pop(i)
    print(dias)
    y += 1
```

Para luego querer visualizar mi diccionario "dias"

```
print(dias)
```

Al final de todo me sale el siguiente error: IndexError: list index out of range.
Porfavor alguien que me oriente en que estoy fallando, o si de la forma en que lo estoy asiendo no es la correcta.
Psdt: La idea es hacerlo con bucles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una forma muy simple, es usar comprensión de listas para reformular el diccionario original:

```
dias = {k.upper(): v for k, v in dias.items()}
print(dias)

{'LUNES': 1, 'MARTES': 2, 'MIERCOLES': 3, 'JUEVES': 4, 'VIERNES': 5, 'SABADO': 6, 'DOMINGO': 7}
```

#### ¿Como funciona?

- con `for k, v in dias.items()` iteramos por cada clave/valor
- con `{k.upper(): v ...}` construímos un nuevo diccionario dónde las claves las pasamos a mayúsculas

#### ¿Y el error del código original?

Básicamente estas modificando el mismo diccionario que está iterando, eso es una fuente de conflictos, podrías eventualmente resolverlo iterando sobre la lista de claves (que es un objeto distinto), por ejemplo: `for i in list(dias)`

Answer (score 4):

El problema aqui es que como el diccionario de días va insertando nuevos valores y eliminando otros, llega un momento en el que modificas unos de los elementos que ya tenias en mayúsculas y vas incrementando el indice y hasta que tiene un valor mayor que el numero de elementos en keys.

Por lo tanto, una solución es recorrer los días mediante una lista, creada mediante los dias que contiene el diccionario, así estos valores no serán modificados, ya que si haces `listaDias = dias`, ambos se modificaran, para evitarlo haces `listadas = list(dias)`

Te he cambiado un poco el código para que sea más legible y unos `print` para que puedas ir viendo como trabaja el programa

```
dias = {
    "lunes": 1,
    "martes": 2,
    "miercoles": 3,
    "jueves": 4,
    "viernes": 5,
    "sabado": 6,
    "domingo": 7
}


keys = list(dias)
x = 0

for k in keys:
     keys[x] = k.upper()
     x += 1



listaDias = list(dias)


y = 0
for dia in listaDias:

      print("Dias antes insertar uno nuevo",dias)
      print("Dias en listaDias: ",listaDias)
      print("Valor Y: ",y)
      print("Dia:",dia)
      print("Key nueva:",keys[y])

      dias[keys[y]] = dias.pop(dia)

      y = y + 1

print(dias)
```

Comment: La idea es que sea todo en mayusculas: LUNES, MARTES, .........

Comment: @SnchzEder Ahi tienes la solución a lo que planteaste, he editado la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Si quitas el `print` que esta dentro del segundo `for` algo así:

```
dias = {
    "lunes": 1,
    "martes": 2,
    "miercoles": 3,
    "jueves": 4,
    "viernes": 5,
    "sabado": 6,
    "domingo": 7
    }

 keys = list(dias)
 x = 0
 for k in keys:
     keys[x] = k.upper()
     x += 1
 y = 0
 for i in dias:
     dias[keys[y]] = dias.pop(i)
     y += 1
 print(dias)
```

El resultado es:

```
{'LUNES': 1, 'SABADO': 6, 'DOMINGO': 7, 'MIERCOLES': 3, 'JUEVES': 4, 'MARTES': 2, 'VIERNES': 5}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Que raro, ami con el mismo codigo me sale el error ya comentado :/

Comment: El print dentro del for lo puse solamente para ver en donde estaba fallando. Pero como te digo, con en ese mismo codigo me sigue botando error :(

Comment: sera cosa del demonio! xD

Answer (score 1):

Saludos podrias realizar lo siguiente:

```
def capitalizar_keys(d):
    result = {}
    for key, value in d.items():
        upper_key = key.upper()
        result[upper_key] = result.get(upper_key, 0) + value
    return result

dias = {
    "lunes": 1,
    "martes": 2,
    "miercoles": 3,
    "jueves": 4,
    "viernes": 5,
    "sabado": 6,
    "domingo": 7
}
result =capitalizar_keys(dias)
```

**Resultado:**

```
{'LUNES': 1, 'MARTES': 2, 'MIERCOLES': 3, 'JUEVES': 4, 'VIERNES': 5, 'SABADO': 6, 'DOMINGO': 7}
```

[image: result]

si te fijas hago una función que recibe mi diccionario y lo convierte a mayúsculas, espero te sirva..!!